# Updating a SharePoint 2013 list with JavaScript, works but not quite

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I am using Script Editor web part to insert data into a SharePoint 2013 list with JavaScript. When I use the following code in the Script Editor, I get the result I want every time the page loads:

```
<script>
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_list');
    var itemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My title testing');
    oListItem.update();
    context.load(oListItem);
</script>
```

After the page loads, I get the new item in *my_list* with *My title testing* in the Title column.

However, I want this to happen when a user clicks on a button. So I created a button with the *onclick* property pointing to a function I've put the above code in, but it doesn't work - nothing happens. This is the contents of the Script Editor after I've put the button and wrapped the script inside a function:

```
<html>
    <button type="button" onclick="addToList()">Submit</button>
</html>

<script>
    function addToList() {
    SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_list');
    var itemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

    this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemInfo);

    oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My title testing');
    oListItem.update();
    context.load(oListItem);
   }
</script>
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: See if you get any javascript error in the console. Perhaps the function does not have access to some variables.

Comment: Nope, all seems to be in order... The code works if it's out of the onclick function. Maybe it's something with this.oListItem? I can't figure it out.

Comment: Try putting `cosole.log` after every command for debugging, to see where the execution stops.

Comment: Still nothing, no errors. I've even logged oItemList in both cases, with the button click and without, and it's the same object. I'll keep digging

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the function before the button:

```
<script>
    function addToList() {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_list');
        var itemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

        this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My title testing');
        oListItem.update();
        context.load(oListItem);
    }
</script>

<html>
    <button type="button" onclick="addToList()">Submit</button>
</html>
```

If this doesn't work, or you don't like it, try attaching the listener from inside the script, like this:

```
<html>
    <button id="myButton" type="button">Submit</button>
</html>

<script>
    function addToList() {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {});
        var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_list');
        var itemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();

        this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemInfo);

        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My title testing');
        oListItem.update();
        context.load(oListItem);
    }

   document.getElementById("myButton").addEventListener("click", addToList);
</script>
```

See working jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o9uLtwec/1/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. The thing is that the function is called on click (if I add a console log in the function, I see it when I click the button), but the inserting into the list doesn't work...

Comment: Not alert, but I added a

console.log('the function is called');

and I see it in the console when I click the button. So the function gets called, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

To add item to list using JSOM, we can use the code below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function addToList() {
    ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function(){
        var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('my_list');
        var itemInfo = new SP.ListItemCreationInformation();
        this.oListItem = list.addItem(itemInfo);
        oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My title testing');
        oListItem.update();
        context.load(oListItem);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);
    }, "sp.js");
}
function onQuerySucceeded() {
    console.log('Item created: ' + oListItem.get_id());
    window.location.href=window.location.href;
}
function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
</script>
<input type="button" onclick="addToList()" value="Submit"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I do it like this, I get the "'addToList' is undefined" in the console when I click on the button. The code works if I put it in on the page without the function, i.e. make it execute when the page loads. It doesn't work inside the function.

Comment: I modify the code above, check if it works in your environment.

Comment: Thanks, but still the same thing.

Comment: I the code into a content editor web part in the list view to check if it works.